# Get value of nested field SOQL

Tags: soql, rest-api

My company has four objects:

1. Opportunity
2. User
3. Project
4. Request

The `Request` object is a child of `Project`, which is itself a child of `Opportunity`. (`Opportunity` > `Project` > `Request`). Each opportunity has an owner.

**How can I get the owner's name in an SOQL query along with information about the request?**

The below request works, but gives me only the owner's ID.

```
SELECT Request__c.Id, Request__c.Name, Opportunity__R.OwnerId FROM Request__c WHERE Request__c.Id='123'
```

If I try to add a nested query like `(SELECT Id FROM Opportunity__r.OwnerId)` or `(SELECT Id FROM User__r)`, I get the respective errors:

> First SObject of a nested query must be a child of its outer query
>
> Didn't understand relationship 'User__r' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this `Owner.Name`

```
SELECT Request__c.Id, Request__c.Name, Opportunity__R.Owner.Name, Owner.Name
FROM Request__c 
WHERE Request__c.Id='123'
```

Comment: `Owner.Name` can't be a standalone field (it errors), but otherwise this works. Thanks.